# Gitlab runner CI/CD do not checkout and pull last commit

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-swarm, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to have a CI/CD with gitlab-runner and docker swarm. I have problem when i deploy the commit will not checkout or checkout without changes, I wonder to know if problem is gitlab or docker or docker build. my .gitlab-ci.yml, look like:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
build_image:
  stage: build
  image: docker:git
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
    - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/insuretech1/backend:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} ./DockerFiles/Worker
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/insuretech1/backend:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  only:
    - branches
deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  image: rastasheep/ubuntu-sshd:latest
  script:
    # add the server as a known host
    - ssh-keyscan 46.4.151.121 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    # add ssh key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - touch key.txt
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" >> key.txt
    - chmod 600 key.txt
    - ssh-add key.txt
    # log into Docker registry
    - ssh alireza@46.4.151.121 "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com"
    # stop container, remove image.
    - ssh alireza@46.4.151.121 "docker stop dockergitlab_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}" || true
    - ssh alireza@46.4.151.121 "docker rm dockergitlab_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}" || true
    - ssh alireza@46.4.151.121 "docker rmi registry.gitlab.com/insuretech1/backend:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}" || true
    # start new container
    - ssh alireza@46.4.151.121 "docker run --name dockergitlab_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} -d registry.gitlab.com/insuretech1/backend:${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master
```

and I also I put my pipeline log below, that might help to describe more:

```
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
00:02
 Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
 Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/insuretech1/backend/.git/
 Created fresh repository.
 From https://gitlab.com/insuretech1/backend
  * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/124187268 -> refs/pipelines/124187268
  * [new branch]      develop                  -> origin/develop
 Checking out 735209a2 as develop...
 Skipping Git submodules setup
$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
03:43
 WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
 WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
 Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
 https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
 Login Succeeded
```

the content of dockerfile which I use for my build

```
FROM debian:buster

MAINTAINER Alireza Rahmani Khalili "alirezarahmani@live.com"

ENV TERM xterm

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y --force-yes curl sudo vim
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes wget apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
RUN wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg

RUN echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
RUN echo "deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian buster-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
RUN echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get update && apt-get install -y --force-yes \
    nginx \
    php7.3 \
    php7.3-cli \
    php7.3-fpm \
    php7.3-curl \
    php7.3-json \
    php7.3-mysql \
    php7.3-sqlite \
    php7.3-xml \
    php7.3-intl \
    php7.3-mbstring \
    php7.3-xdebug \
    php-memcached \
    git \
    openssh-server \
    php7.3-gd \
    zip \
    php7.3-zip

# configure php-fpm
RUN sed -i 's/^;*clear_env = .*/clear_env = no/' /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:root' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
RUN echo "UseDNS no" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN echo "KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN echo "fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;" >> /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
RUN openssl ecparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key -name prime256v1 -genkey
RUN openssl req -new -batch -key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/csr.pem
RUN openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key -in /etc/nginx/ssl/csr.pem -out /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.pem
RUN chmod 600 /etc/nginx/ssl/*

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

ADD docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/^user  nginx;/user  www-data;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN echo "apc.enable_cli=1" >> /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
RUN echo "apc.shm_size=128M" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-apcu.ini
RUN sed -i "s/\(max_execution_time *= *\).*/\1180/" /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini
RUN sed -i "s/\(upload_max_filesize *= *\).*/\1100M/" /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini
RUN sed -i "s/\(post_max_size *= *\).*/\1100M/" /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini
RUN sed -i "s/\(^.*max_input_vars *= *\).*/max_input_vars = 10000/" /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini
RUN sed -i "s/\(pm.max_children = 5\).*/\pm.max_children = 50/" /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
RUN sed -i "s/\(pm.max_spare_servers = 3\).*/\pm.max_spare_servers = 10/" /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
RUN echo "xdebug.default_enable=1" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/var/www/cachegrind/" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.profiler_output_name= cachegrind.out" >> /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/

ADD default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
ADD default.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

EXPOSE 22 443 80
WORKDIR /var/www/

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and also content of my docker compose file which i use when I build in my ci/cd:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  worker:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/insuretech1/backend:develop
    ports:
    - 0.0.0.0:80:80
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3
      # service resource management
      resources:
        # Hard limit - Docker does not allow to allocate more
        limits:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 512M
        # Soft limit - Docker makes best effort to return to it
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 256M
      # service restart policy
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      # service update configuration
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
        failure_action: continue
        monitor: 60s
        max_failure_ratio: 0.3
    volumes:
    - /var/www/backend:/var/www
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    ports:
    - 0.0.0.0:3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - /opt/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
  redis:
    image: redis
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

the issue is I can not see my last changes of my commit in my server (I mean i should manually git pull to fetch last changes), is there anything wrong?

Comment: What do pipeline logs say about checkout? It should look like `Checking out <commit sha> as <branch name>...`. You needn't perform any git operations to have changes from commit that triggered the pipeline.

Comment: @makozaki pipeline log is added to question

Comment: So `Checking out 735209a2 as develop...` is this the commit which changes you cannot see?

Comment: @makozaki i made change in public/index.php but the changes are not into this file

Comment: Did you push the changes correctly?

Comment: @makozaki yes, i directly edit file on gitlab and also when i run git pull origin develop i can see changes

Comment: Then I would look for the problem elsewhere. I would start with analyzing Dockerfile used for build.

Comment: @makozaki i added content of dockefile and docker compose

Comment: So you made some changes directly on gitlab in `public/index.php`. Making code changes directly on gitlab seems like a bad idea. Did you check these changes locally? I'm starting to think that you don't know what you are doing and asked first question that poped. Better think this through and ask question when you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all in your Dockerfile  you should copy content of directory into docker container. that will help you keep git changes with your container, for example:

```
COPY . /var/www/
```

and other problem is in your docker compose file you have:

```
    volumes:
    - /var/www/backend:/var/www
```

this will override changes that git made on your container and that is why you are not able to see git changes.